# C Programming How to find the time interval between events

Tags: time, rpm, intervals

Im using a handyboard and interactive c software and the task is to find the rpm of a lego motor in real time using an Infrared "Break Beam" Sensor on the wheel. I was thinking about finding the time interval between the beam being broken and then from there calculating the rpm but i cant figure out exactly how to do that. Any help would be much appreciated thanks.

Comment: what resolution do you need? seconds? nilliseconds?

Comment: Also, what platform is handyboard?  Unix-based?

Comment: milliseconds. im not sure what platform it is actualy.

Answer (score 1):

Do mean something like this: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/ctime/

I believe there a better resolution ones out there (as Neil is implying), but this is the simplest.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to Win32 then you can use [QueryPerformanceFrequency](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644905(VS.85).aspx) to calculate the time of the interval. It's also often being used to determine the amount of frames per seconds in games, so it's very precise.

Answer (score 0):

I have a handy board myself, since you are using a v9 motor, arent you?
I am sure you could jsut calculate it from the voltage thats being applied to the motor.
Additionally a good reference, [Robotic Exploration](http://realengineer.com/7488/robotic-explorations-a-hands-on-introduction-to-engineering/)

Comment: lol, just realised that this post is two years old, i just searched for 'handyboard' questions since I am working with one right now :-)